# Gazebo: one of my robot's wheels stick to the ground and don't spin correctly

Tags: gazebo, urdf, nxt, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I was going to test the robot I just wrote in Gazebo when I realized that the robot spins around the joint of the caster instead of the other way around...

I mean, the continuous joint that simulates the axle of the caster spins, yes, but it's the wheel that stays in the same place (like if it were glued to the ground) while the robot does a backflip around it when I turn on the front wheels' motors, for example.

I have no clue about the reason of this. I think that everything is defined the way it has to be, but clearly I'm missing something.

The .xacro files can be found [here](http://bit.ly/LbrXKO). The caster can be found inside [nxt_caster.xacro](http://bit.ly/LbuF2Q), but some things like <gazebo> parameters are inside [nxt_base.xacro](http://bit.ly/LbuSCY).

Anyway, if you want, you can test the problem yourselves if you have the nxt stack, clone the [repository](http://bit.ly/J4Diwa) (or just download the code), compile it and then:

```
roslaunch nxt_gazebo nxt_ultrasonic_empty_world.launch
```

and (try to) drive it around with:

```
roslaunch nxt_teleop teleop_keyboard.launch
```

If you need me to explain anything else on my code just ask!

Thanks in advance,
Miguel.

**Edit**: I uploaded a [video showing the problem](http://youtu.be/qSYyP4psdrQ), as you can see, the caster wheel sticks to the ground whenever it touches it.

**Edit**: I tried changing the mu1 and mu2 parameters, the transmission, the continuous joint parameters... Nothing seems to change the problem of the wheel sticking to the ground as if it was glued down.

**Edit**: I used my caster macro in another .urdf file ([video](http://bit.ly/LO36wJ), as you can see it spins correctly when I move around the robot, despite the bouncing.) with more satisfactory results, so it seems that the problem **is not in the caster definition itself**, but anywhere else. That leaves me even more confused and still without any clue about how to fix it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37084/gazebo:-one-of-my-robot%27s-wheels-stick-to-the-ground-and-don%27t-spin-correctly/) by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I've found the solution, so I'm posting it here just in case anyone else find themselves in the same situation:

I was applying way too much effort on the motors, causing the wheels to jump off the ground instead of working properly.

---

Originally posted by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) with karma: 202 on 2012-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2014-10-02**:
hey how are you applying effor or velocity on the motor. using pr2_controller_manager or something else. Evenif I have tried with this still mi robot is not moving in the gazebo simulator